# How to make sure our script is using a proxy

Tags: mac, proxy, python

I have a python script I made which requests pages on the web. I am using a mac os and am using a socks proxy on 127.0.0.1:9150 on my wifi (pass all apps thru proxy --tor--). Using wireshark, how do I know it is using the proxy for sure? I can view every request in plain text!

Note: I know my browsers are well setup with tor.

Comment: Submit a request to a IP echo service?...

http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: @JasonSec Hi, I just did it, and it prints out my real ip adress.

Comment: well then you know your python script is not using the proxy.

Comment: @JasonSec Right, well do you know how to make sure it uses the proxy or I create a new post for that?

Comment: You should post a description of your problem and the relevant python code that makes the request to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or another programming Q/A forum, yes.

Answer (score -1):

check your ip

```
session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {}
session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9150'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9150'
r = session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip")
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer.